# Activating extension undefined_publisher.<extension> failed: Cannot find module 'node:process'

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, webpack

Ola,
I am currently working on a (mostly unaltered) javascript vscode extension, and I'd like to copy something to the clipboard with it. For this I want to use [clipboardy](https://github.com/sindresorhus/clipboardy), but when I simply import clipboardy the extension fails and gives the following error:

```
Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.sottkrdomg' failed: Cannot find module 'node:process'
Require stack:
- c:\Users\bobde\Desktop\Local_repos_and_projects\(JS) SOTTKRDOMG\dist\extension.js
- c:\Users\bobde\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js
- c:\Users\bobde\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js
- c:\Users\bobde\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork.js.
```

My version of node is v17.3.1, vscode engine 1.63.0, OS is Windows 10. I had no issue with using clipboardy in regular node, using a fresh js vscode extension does not help.

My jsconfig:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES2020",
        "checkJs": true,  /* Typecheck .js files. */
        "lib": [
            "ES2020"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

My webpack config:

```js
const path = require("path");
module.exports = [{
  target: 'node', // vscode extensions run in a Node.js-context  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/
    mode: 'none', // this leaves the source code as close as possible to the original (when packaging we set this to 'production')

  entry: './src/extension.js', // the entry point of this extension,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
  output: {
    // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json),  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'extension.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  externals: {
    vscode: 'commonjs vscode' // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
    // modules added here also need to be added in the .vscodeignore file
  },
  resolve: {
    // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files,  -> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
    extensions: ['.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
  infrastructureLogging: {
    level: "log", // enables logging required for problem matchers
  },
}];
```

I would like to be able to use this library, I've not had issues with other libraries so far, and I am really curious what the issue could be. Any help is appericiated!